# Importing csv data to data frame not working

Tags: r

I try to load data from a csv to a data frame. What I do is that:

```
input <- read.csv("CONCAT_RESULT.CSV", sep = ",", skip = 1, col.names = c("ABS_ERG","MEHRFACH_COUNTER","TECH_KEY","XX_KEY","YY_SCHLUESSEL","CCC","LAND","HIERARCHIE_STICHTAGSABZUG","DATUM_SST_ERZEUGUNG","UHRZEIT_SST_ERZEUGUNG","FRUEHESTES_ABZUGSDATUM","AGGR_KLASSE_ID","ANTWORT_NUM","ANTWORT_TEXT","UMFRAGETYP_ID","ZZZ_ID","TTT_ID","BEANTWORTUNG_TYP","TRANSFORMIERT"))
```

In the next step I remove a few columns:

```
input["HIERARCHIE_STICHTAGSABZUG"] <- NULL
input["DATUM_SST_ERZEUGUNG"] <- NULL
input["UHRZEIT_SST_ERZEUGUNG"] <- NULL
input["FRUEHESTES_ABZUGSDATUM"] <- NULL
input["ANTWORT_TEXT"] <- NULL
```

Then I try to convert it to a data.frame with:

```
input.data <- as.data.frame(input)
```

But `typeof(input.data)` returns: `[1] "list"`

Can anybody tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: `data.frame` inherits from `list`. Try `class(input.data)` to have the class of an object. The result of `read.csv` is already a `data.frame`, so no need to call `as.data.frame`. Read also `?typeof` to see which output `typeof` can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data.frame is a list of vectors of the same length. Thus, `list` is a correct type for a `data.frame`.

Try

```
typeof(data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3))
```

to see, that a data.frame is just a list. To learn more, see `help(mode)` and `help(data.frame)`.